# Synchronize selection of sortable QTableWidgets

Tags: c++, qt, qtablewidget, qtablewidgetitem, qmodelindex

I have two QTableWidgets, having the same number of rows and columns. Now, every selection in one table should automatically update the selection in the other and vice versa.

The following code works fine, with one exception:

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QTableWidget>
#include <QHBoxLayout>
#include <functional>

QTableWidget* create() {
    auto table = new QTableWidget;
    table->setSortingEnabled(true);
    table->setRowCount(20);
    table->setColumnCount(1);
    for (auto i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
        {
            auto item = new QTableWidgetItem(QString("%1").arg(i+1));
            table->setItem(i, 1, item);
        }
    }
    return table;
}
int main(int argc, char** args) {
    QApplication app(argc, args);

    QTableWidget* table1 = create();
    QTableWidget* table2 = create();
    auto frame = new QFrame;
    frame->setLayout(new QHBoxLayout);
    frame->layout()->addWidget(table1);
    frame->layout()->addWidget(table2);
    frame->show();
    auto func = [&](QTableWidget* senderTable, QTableWidget* receiverTable) {
        const QSignalBlocker blocker(receiverTable);
        receiverTable->selectionModel()->clearSelection();
        for (auto item : senderTable->selectedItems()) {
            receiverTable->item(item->row(), item->column())->setSelected(true);
        }
    };

    QObject::connect(table2, &QTableWidget::itemSelectionChanged, std::bind(func, table2, table1));
    QObject::connect(table1, &QTableWidget::itemSelectionChanged, std::bind(func, table1, table2));
    app.exec();
}
```

The exceptions occurs, if I sort one column. In this case the `wrong` items are selected in the other table.

[image: Wrong selection occurred if sorting is enabled.]

In other words the behavior of the selection synchronization should be independent of a selected sorting. The contents of my tables are just examples.

What might be the easiest way to achieve the desired behavior?

Comment: Do you mean that when you select the row that contains data 11 in the left table the selected row in the right table should be the one that contains the same data (11) and not the one with the same row index?

Comment: That's my point. You got it.

Answer (score 0):

I have modified your example to make it work as intended. The idea is that we shouldn't rely on items' rows and columns, but rather store some unique identifiers in each of the items and perform lookup rather by that identifier than by row and column, which can be different depending on the sort order.

So, here is the code that demonstrates what I said:

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QTableWidget>
#include <QHBoxLayout>
#include <functional>
#include <assert.h>

QTableWidget* create()
{
  auto table = new QTableWidget;
  table->setSortingEnabled(true);
  table->setRowCount(20);
  table->setColumnCount(1);
  for (auto i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
    auto item = new QTableWidgetItem(QString("%1").arg(i + 1));
    item->setData(Qt::UserRole, i); // It can be any kind of unique identifier.
    table->setItem(i, 1, item);
  }
  return table;
}

int main(int argc, char** args)
{
  QApplication app(argc, args);

  QTableWidget* table1 = create();
  QTableWidget* table2 = create();
  auto frame = new QFrame;
  frame->setLayout(new QHBoxLayout);
  frame->layout()->addWidget(table1);
  frame->layout()->addWidget(table2);
  frame->show();
  auto func = [&](QTableWidget* senderTable, QTableWidget* receiverTable) {
    const QSignalBlocker blocker(receiverTable);
    receiverTable->selectionModel()->clearSelection();
    auto model = receiverTable->model();
    for (auto item : senderTable->selectedItems()) {
      // Find the item with the same identifier.
      auto found = model->match(model->index(0, 0), Qt::UserRole, item->data(Qt::UserRole));
      assert(!found.empty());
      auto idx = found.first();
      receiverTable->item(idx.row(), idx.column())->setSelected(true);
    }
  };

  QObject::connect(table2, &QTableWidget::itemSelectionChanged, std::bind(func, table2, table1));
  QObject::connect(table1, &QTableWidget::itemSelectionChanged, std::bind(func, table1, table2));
  app.exec();
}
```